# How to check dataset refresh history for all datasets in PowerBi service

Tags: powerbi

Scenario as follows:

There are 10 workspaces within PowerBI service.
There are multiple reports in each workspaces. There are 5 datasets in each workspace which are scheduled to refresh daily every morning.

You can view the refresh statistics for an individual dataset such as status, start and completed times.

Has anyone come across a method to have a complete overall view for all datasets refresh statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can go into the service and look at the refresh history in the dataset settings. Or you can use the Power BI API to get the refresh history

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistory

You'll need to get the steps of:
1) Get list of the workspaces
2) Get list of datasets 
3) Get the refresh history

You'll have to code an iterative process that loops through stages 1 & 2 to get the detail on all the datasets.

Comment: have you come across any good examples/tutorials of implementing your sugestion with SSIS? I am thinking of using SSIS to retrieve the stats and storing to a DB table and building a report respectively.